# I need string that starts with number from my input string

Tags: android, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my code

```
String itemName = "Daily 60k tube";
  String name="";
  if(itemName.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
        {
            itemName = itemName.substring(itemName.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            itemName = itemName.substring(0, itemName.indexOf(" "));
            name = itemName;
        }
```

I need that 60k as my name in the output. But it is crashing with exception.
This is the exception.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
                                                                at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
                                                                at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
```

My output should be "60k". Please help me fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't be use `split` or `indexOf` function for string?

Comment: can you suggest with example.

Comment: is it fixed you will get same kind of string? i mean "Daily 60k tube" type?

Comment: @vrund purohit I will get different values like "Daily cube only 50k" and output should be "50k" only.

Comment: @Android. .Please check my anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
String itemName = "Daily 60k tube";
String name="";
if(itemName.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
{
    String[] array = itemName.split(" "); // Daily 60k tube
    // array: {"Daily","60k","tube"}
    for (String item : array) {
        if (item.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
             name = item;
         }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** You can also replace the line with this

```
  (item.matches(".*\\d+.*" + "k")
```

So it will look like

```
    String[] array = itemName.split(" "); // Daily 60k tube
    // array: {"Daily","60k","tube"}
    for (String item : array) {
        if (item.matches(".*\\d+.*" + "k") {
             name = item;
         }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will get different values like "Daily cube only 50k" and output should be "50k" only.

Comment: this is working but I will get different strings wait.. I will update my question.

Comment: Hope it helped..Thanks :): ) Happie coding @Android

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code

```
String Name;
String[] array = itemName.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
    if(Character.isDigit(array[i].charAt(0)))
    {
        Name = array[i];
        break;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: if you found it helpful to you and it resolves what you want kindly mark this as answer so that it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you.

```
 int i=itemName.indexOf(" ") + 1;
    itemName = itemName.substring(i);
    i=itemName.indexOf(" ");
    itemName = itemName.substring(0,i);
    name = itemName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
private static String getResult(String itemName) {
        String[] result = itemName.split(" ");
        for (String i : result) {
            if (Character.isDigit(i.charAt(0))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```